# Show HyperLinks in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, url, gridview, hyperlink, datatable

I have an XML file and it contains data about products,and the most interesting data is a url that takes user to the page of thah product.I have successfully extracted urls from that XML file into XmlNodeList and then I put them into DataTable so these urls can be displayed in ASPxGridview.But these urls are shown as text and are not clickable.How to convert the text into HyperLinks?Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a HyperLinkField: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.aspx

You'd bind the url to the `DataNagivateUrlFields` property.

Edit with code example:

```
<asp:gridview id="gv1" 
    autogeneratecolumns="true"
    runat="server">
    <columns>          
      <asp:hyperlinkfield text="View Product"
        DataNavigateUrlFields="url"
        />
    </columns>
  </asp:gridview>
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply.I've already tried to use HyperLinkField but I couldn't make it work because my GridView fills with data dynamically.I don't know how many HyperLinkFields I need.In which code part should I set HyperLinkFields,while putting data into DataTable?

Comment: Do you have multiple url fields, or is there always the same number of url fields?  If the url fields are constant, you can create HyperLinkFields for them, then continue dynamically creating columns for other data.

Comment: I have more than 100 products in XML file.Every one of them has only one url.So,in my GridView I have only one column that contains urls.Can you please write me some code.Thank you!

Comment: Edited with a gridview that you can get started with.

Comment: OK,thank you very much.But how do I iterate through the all urls?How to create more than one HyperLinkField?

Comment: You put your XML in a DataTable, so you don't need to iterate.  Set `gv1.DataSource = DataTable;` then `gv1.DataBind();`

Comment: OK,I have already done that.So it should work now?I can't try the code now because I'm not at work.

Comment: Yeah, when you get in to work, try it and let me know how it goes.

Comment: It works now,but the problem is that Text property will always be the same = "View Product" but for the Text I need the whole URL.So,the Text has to be the same as URL.